# Does join ordering matter in sql?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using postgresql, suppose I am having two tables one is user(name,age,comment_id) and other is comment(comment_id, text) , now there are billions of users but thousands of comments. Does the order in which joins are written in where clause matters?

Ex : Query 1

```
select a.name, b.text 
from user as a, comment as b
where 
   b.comment_id = 1 and
   a.comment_id = b.comment_id
```

Ex : Query 2

```
select a.name, b.text 
from user as a, comment as b
where 
  a.comment_id = b.comment_id and
  b.comment_id = 1
```

Comment: Postgre changes that to the correct way of doing joins but for reference not all SQL engines to this so please use the join keyword :)

Comment: For future reference that way of doing it is a cartesian product on Table A and B, definitely something you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The join order does not matter for inner joins, but it does matter for outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read your code you don't use any join at all. You create the whole cartesian product and then filter with WHERE. Let's hope your query optimizer takes care of that.

And yes, it does matter. Always try to do the more selective (which kills more rows from the cartesian product) first and take a look at the QEP of your DBMS.

Your query should read something like:

```
select a.name, b.text from
user as a
[left|right|inner|outer] join comment as b on a.comment_id = b.comment_id
where b.comment_id = 1
```

Comment: Postgre does take care of that but yeah bad practice :)

Comment: Tanks for reply, This is just an example, means I have much bigger data such that I have to query 10 tables and use 20-25 joins. How can I use keyword "join" in such case.

Comment: @Jesus The as is optional. Edits should correct errors or format, but not change one's code to just another format. From the postgres doc: table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias [ ( column_alias [, ...] ) ] ]

Comment: @Hyperboreus, My mistake I typically use the AS keyword even in PostGre never knew it was optional.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: of course those are joins. It's the "official" join syntax before the JOIN keyword was introduced in SQL 1999.

Comment: @Jesus: The name is either 'Postgres' or 'PostgreSQL', never PostGre :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was my keyboard's bad it's got a bad shift key and I tend to rest my pinky on it.

Answer (score 0):

Join order does not matter until you hit thresholds. One threshold makes the Geqo kick in, the other two kick in when the number of explicit and implicit joins is too great.

In the where clause, order is irrelevant and PG reserves the right to reorder everything based on boolean logic. This makes this query dangerous:

```
select 1 from stuff where x <> 0 and y / x > 1 -- should use case instead
```